# Summation question?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, summation, assumptions

I have following summation that I want to implement using Mathematica:

```
Sum[
 If[m == 0 && n == 0
  , Nothing
  , (1/z^2 + (1/(z - (m 2 π + n 2 π τ))^2 - 
         1/((m 2 π + 
              n 2 π τ))^2) /. {z -> π τ}) - (1/
        z^2 + (1/(z - (m 2 π + n 2 π τ))^2 - 
         1/((m 2 π + n 2 π τ))^2) /. z -> π) // 
   Simplify
  ], {m, -∞, ∞}, {n, -∞, ∞}
 ]
```

Above code returns the following result:

$-\frac{2 \left(\tau ^2-1\right)}{\pi ^2 \tau ^2}$

However, if I remove the `If` command in the above summation, Mathematica doesn't do the summation anymore, but I know the above expression  is finite when `m=0&&n=0`. What's going on here?

Comment: I'missing "if command"

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Ooops, I have copied the code without if

Comment: The sum as written diverges. But `Sum` is not handling that `If` in the way you might expect, and that result is simply the value when `m,n=0`.

Comment: What do you expect of using `Nothing` inside `Sum`? It has no sense.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks! I didn't know that. Any idea on analyzing how this summation diverges as a function of $\tau$?

Comment: @azerbajdzan Thanks! I was expecting it to skip the summation of m=0&&n=0. I guess it doesn't work this way.

Comment: The main issue is that there is a nonzero constant term in the summand. Even with that removed I do not think `Sum` will manage this though.

Answer (score 0):

For Timing reasons, its not  a good idea to Simplify inside a sum, because Sum has Attribute HoldFirst, meaning that each summand is simplified with actual numbers n,m. But this sum has to be evaluated algebraically (or by table lookup).

Simplification reveals two problems, removal of 1/m^2, 1/n^2 at infinity and

```
(1/z^2 + (1/(z - (m 2 \[Pi] + n 2 \[Pi] \[Tau]))^2 - 
   1/((m 2 \[Pi] + 
        n 2 \[Pi] \[Tau]))^2) /. {z -> \[Pi] \[Tau]}) - (1/
  z^2 + (1/(z - (m 2 \[Pi] + n 2 \[Pi] \[Tau]))^2 - 
   1/((m 2 \[Pi] + n 2 \[Pi] \[Tau]))^2) /. 
z -> \[Pi]) // Simplify
```

$$\frac{1}{(2 \pi  m+2 \pi  n \tau -\pi  \tau )^2}-\frac{1}{(-2 \pi  m-2 \pi  n \tau +\pi )^2}+\frac{\frac{1}{\tau ^2}-1}{\pi ^2}$$

a constant term, that, in a double sum, occurs inifintely often.

Probably, there is a wrong  sign of the compensating constant for the limit $n,m\to 0$

```
  \[Pi]^2 FullSimplify@ExpandAll[(-1 + 1/\[Tau]^2)/\[Pi]^2 - 
    1/(\[Pi] - 2 m \[Pi] - 2 n \[Pi] \[Tau])^2 + 
  1/(2 m \[Pi] - \[Pi] \[Tau] + 2 n \[Pi] \[Tau])^2 /. {n ->  0}]
```

$$\frac{1}{(\tau -2 m)^2}-\frac{1}{(1-2 m)^2}+\frac{1}{\tau ^2}-1$$